# Packet capturing for a simple IDS in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, packet-sniffers, packet-capture, ids

I am thinking of developing cross platform Intrusion Detection System. I am researching its development feasibility using flutter for the front end. Is that a good idea? One thing that's bugging me is the packet capturing. Are there packages in flutter that are useful for that purpose?

I have queried openai's chatgpt for a general idea but its answer is that there is no a crossplatform implementation of packet capturing package in flutter but you can write a platform specific code.